# Can I re-cook pre-cooked conch?

Tags: seafood

My local store only carries pre-cooked conch meat. I cut it very thinly for my salad yet I still find it tough.

My question is: Can I recook my conch meat to tenderize it? I have tried to find fresh conch meat locally but there is nothing available.

I know that I could easily go buy some to try this method; however, at the price per lb. I hate to throw away the money.

Answer (score 2):

According to [ochef](http://www.ochef.com/150.htm), conch is tender only if barely cooked or simmered for at least an hour.  If your conch is tough, it was probably cooked too long but yet not long enough.  You may want to give it a light pressing (not pounding) with a kitchen mallet and then simmer it in fish stock for an hour or so.